# Identify android device when dealing with money transaction

Tags: android

Now that android does not let us use the IMEI number, I am unsure about what to use for my use case which is dealing with real money transactions.

The android guidelines states this:
**Use a Firebase installation ID (FID) or a privately stored GUID whenever possible for all other use cases, except for payment fraud prevention and telephony.**

But I was unable to find anywhere that suggests what to do **for payment fraud prevention and telephony.**

Currently I have decided to work with SSAID, but I would really appreciate if someone in the community provides some insight to this or can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: Now We use the UUID and the UDID which is the Unique ID

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa, would this UUID or UDID will be acceptable as unique ids with payment gateways in case of any conflict or fraud situation?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf i went thorough the post, and i am aware of different ways to try and create a unique Id, I m just confused which would be acceptable when dealing with real money transaction conflict situation.

Comment: Yes and no it depending on how you write it... Like usually I will store UDID and store it and the UDID will be verified in server side. UDID is something like the device ID provide by the os